# Hadoop-Spark-HBase Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

Getting below error when trying to run job to extract data from HBase table via spark. Any help is highly appreciated.

Error:

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException:
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
> com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator

```
Hadoop Version: 3.1.1
HBase Version: 2.1.6
SPARK Version: 2.3.2
```

```sh
spark-submit --master yar  --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf --class CLASS_NAME --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ JAR_FILE_NAME
```

POM Dependencies:

```xml
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
           
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.11</version>
  </dependency>
            
 <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.2</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.25</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.25</version>
 </dependency>
    

<dependency>
  <groupId>it.nerdammer.bigdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-hbase-connector_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run compatible versions of Hbase and Hadoop.

As your Hadoop version is 3.1.1, try to use `HBase-2.2.x` or `HBase-2.3.x` Hbase versions instead of `2.1.x`.

You can find the Hbase [Hadoop version support matrix](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I will check with our Admin team.

Comment: I did talk to Admins and looks like cloudera support engineer as well looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I got a break through.

It is so simple. just add a statement --jars /usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/shaded-clients/hbase-shaded-mapreduce-2.1.6.3.1.5.0-152.jar into your spark-submit command.

Thanks!